# Passing a class object to a list table

Tags: c++, arrays, list, class

I have  a struct list, a class `castomer`. I want to store my `castomer` to the list. For that I am creating a `castomer` each time and I strore them to a list table. There are no errors except that the program crashes each time I try to store a `castomer` into my table. 
I have this list and class:

```
class castomer{
private:
 string name;
 string lastname;
 int number;
 double time;
public:
    void setAll(string,string,int,double);
    int numberR(){return number;}
    double timeR(){return time;}
    void displayAll();
};

struct node {
castomer person;
struct node *next;
};
```

This function for adding `castomer`:

```
void add(clock_t *start,struct node *table[])
{
 *start = clock();
 double time=(double)*start;
 int i=0;
 while(table[i]!=NULL)
 {
     i++;
 }
if(i > 24)
    cout << "We are not able to add another castomer becase we are full please wait for ont to go "<<endl;
else{
    castomer c1;
    cout<<i;
    cout<< "Give me the castomers name and lastname :";
    string temp1,temp2;
    cin>>temp1;
    cin>>temp2;
    c1.setAll(temp1,temp2,i,time);
    table[i]->person=c1;//my program crases here anyone knows why?
}
}
```

ps: In my main the `table[]` looks like this `struct node * table[25];`

Comment: Can your `table` be a `std::vector`, `std::list`, or `std::array` instead of passing around raw arrays with pointers? Also once you define `node` as a `struct`, you shouldn't keep re-declaring it as a `struct` every time you use it.

Comment: Your `table` is an array and not a list. And you don't seem to allocate the entries in the table, please show a more complete example of your code, how you declare and initialize the table, and how you call the `add` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node* table[25]
```

This is declaring table to be an array of 25 pointers. You have to allocate memory for each of these pointers which from looking at your code is missing.

Answer (score 0):

After your while-loop, `table[i]` will be `NULL`.

```
table[i]->person = c1; // Your program crashes here because of that.
```

Using your code as it is, you should do

```
table[i] = new node;
table[i]->person = c1;
```

But the code looks very strange, like you want to implement a linked list (the `node` structure) but are sticking to using arrays for some reason.
If you're aiming for a linked list, you need to rethink a lot of your code.
If you're not, you can lose the `node` type completely.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using (or trying to use) C++ I will make mention of a few things you can do to improve your code and make your own life easier.

**In C++ you can define constructors for initializing objects.**

Your function `setAll` is a bad practice. You don't really want to change all data of a person after you have created. You just want to **initialize** the data at creation time. Well use **constructors**.

**You don't need pointers**

For what you want to do you don't need complicate the code using **pointers** you could pass the arguments [by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/).

**You are using C++, use STL**

Specifically **[vector](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)** I guarantee it, will help you.

**Use `cout <<`  for displaying yuor object**

you could add a `friend ostream& operator<<` function to your class in order to be able to write code like:

```
Customer a;
cout << a << endl;
```

---

### A complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Customer
{
    public:
        Customer(){}                    // default constructor.
        Customer(string pname, string plastname): name(pname), lastname(plastname)
        {
            id = ++idgen;               // Set an id number.
            time = (double)clock();     // initialize time.
        }   
        int getId() {return id;}        // former numberR().
        double getTime() {return time;} // former timeR().

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Customer obj)
        {out << obj.name << " " << obj.lastname << ". " << "Id: " << obj.id << " Time: " << obj.time;}

    private:
        static int idgen;               // static values are a good way for keep some sort of id.
        int id;                         // former member: number.
        double time;                    // Why don't use clock_t directly?
        string name, lastname;
};

int Customer::idgen = 0;    // Initialize static variable.

int main()
{

    int const MAX_NUMBER_PERSONS = 2;

    std::vector<Customer> customer_list;

    string name, lastname;
    while (customer_list.size() < MAX_NUMBER_PERSONS)
    {
        cout << "Give me the castomers name and lastname <name> <lastname>:";
        cin >> name >> lastname;
        customer_list.push_back(Customer(name, lastname));
    }


    for (auto &x: customer_list)    // If you're learnign C++ its a good moment for search 
    {                               // for c++11 doc.
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```